# How i can push new view when i use coordinator with mvvm-c Rxswift?

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm, viewmodel, rx-swift

i works with MVVM-C (Rxswift) i have to create homeVC , HomeViewModel and HomeCoordinator 
when i try to connect HomeCoordinator with HomeViewModel  to push new VC to Coordinator it's not take any action 
Can any one help me with example or explain how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example will help you:

```swift
//
//  ExampleLiftData.swift
//
//  Created by Daniel Tartaglia on 2/18/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Daniel Tartaglia. MIT License.
//
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxEnumKit
import EnumKit

// MARK: - ExamplePresenter
func presentExample(window: UIWindow) {
    let value = PublishSubject<String>()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Example", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! ExampleViewController
    let action = controller.install(viewModel: exampleViewModel(value: value.asObservable()))
    _ = action
        .filter(case: ExampleAction.showRequest)
        .flatMap { [unowned controller] _ in
            presentRequest(on: controller, title: "", message: "Add how much?")
        }
        .bind(to: value)
    window.rootViewController = controller
}

enum ExampleAction: CaseAccessible {
    case showRequest
}

// MARK: - ExampleViewModel
func exampleViewModel(value: Observable<String>) -> (ExampleInput) -> (ExampleOutput, Observable<ExampleAction>) {
    return { input in
        let state = value
            .compactMap { Int($0) }
            .scan(0, accumulator: +)
            .startWith(0)
        return (
            ExampleOutput(text: state.map { "\($0)" }),
            input.buttonTapped.map { ExampleAction.showRequest }
        )
    }
}

struct ExampleInput {
    let buttonTapped: Observable<Void>
}

// MARK: - ExampleView
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, HasViewModel {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var buildOutput: (ExampleInput) -> ExampleOutput = { _ in fatalError() }
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let input = ExampleInput(
            buttonTapped: button.rx.tap.asObservable()
        )
        let output = buildOutput(input)
        output.text.bind(to: label.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

struct ExampleOutput {
    let text: Observable<String>
}

// MARK: - AlertPresenter
func presentRequest(on root: UIViewController, title: String, message: String) -> Observable<String> {
    let result = PublishSubject<String>()
    let controller = UIAlertController(title: title.isEmpty ? nil : title, message: message.isEmpty ? nil : message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    controller.addTextField(configurationHandler: { $0.keyboardType = .numberPad })
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [unowned controller] _ in
        result.onNext(controller.textFields?[0].text ?? "")
        result.onCompleted()
    })
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        result.onCompleted()
    })
    controller.addAction(ok)
    controller.addAction(cancel)
    root.present(controller, animated: true)
    return result
}
```

Learn more at https://github.com/danielt1263/RxEarthquake